# How to Direct multiple hosts from traefik 2 to one nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, drupal, traefik

I want to route test1.test and test2.test to different folders in an nginx php config using traefik 2. Both are PHP applications.

Here is my nginx site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test1.test
    root /var/www/html/test1;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test2.test
    root /var/www/html/test2;
}
```

and here is mij docker-compose file for the traefik container

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./configurations:/configurations
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

And the docker-compose for my applications

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: test_nginx
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/server.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ../../src:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - proxy
      - internal
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`test1.test`) || Host(`test2.test`)"
  php:
    build: ./php
    container_name: test_php
    ports:
       - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ../../src:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - internal
```

My hostsfile is all set and pointing to localhost (172.0.0.1)

But when browsing to
test1.local it gives 404 file not found
and browsing to test2.test is gives 404 not found nginx.

What I want to do is basicly have one traefik2, one nginx with multiple drupal sites after it.

Can someone explain me how to have 2 hosts pointing to same nginx and redirecting to the correct folder? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Update your label

```
"traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(\`test1.test\`) || Host(\`test2.test\`)"
```

to

```
"traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(\`test1.test\`,\`test2.test\`)"
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two spellings? Shouldn't both work? An "or" by means of || comes to the same thing, doesn't it?